# How to set "KeepAlive" or similar parameter for jmeter Point-to-point sampler to re-use connections?

Tags: jmeter, jms

My Jmeter script has a JMS point-to-point sampler that sends JMS message to an ActiveMQ queue. During the load test we realized that the Jmeter connections to the AMQ were neither getting closed nor were re-used, hence causing connection leak and eventually the messages were refused by the broker. I do not see any option in the sampler to say re-use or close-connection. Whats the way I can achieve this? I would appreciate any alternative to using point to point as well, such as a java sampler which may help achieve the same result.

I expect the JMS connections created by Jmeter are re-used and avoid a connection leak. Any parameter similar to "KeepAlive" in http request available for JMS samplers?

point to point sampler config below
[JMS Point to Point Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbJmd.png)

Comment: Hi Vaishali, can you post your current JMeter configuration (minus the passwords) ? What you are looking for is probably an ActiveMQ connection URI parameter as described here: https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri

Comment: Hi Axel, thank you for your response, I have added the point to point sampler config image above. In above link you provided which config can be used for "connection pool" settings? and where/how do I define that in Jmeter

Comment: I have provided the Jmeter config image above